# asp.net - build linkedin style photo cropper

Tags: asp.net, photo-management

On linkedin.com, the photo that you can manage for your profile has the ability to select a "region" from the photo to crop and use as your profile picture.

I assume that it uploads the original picture to a server, and then stores the x,y of the top left corner, and the width and height.

Does anyone know of a web example of something like this?  The platform is asp.net 3.5, ideally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out - this might be of help

http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/javascript-image-cropper-ui-using-prototype-scriptaculous/

has a demo at

http://www.defusion.org.uk/demos/060519/cropper.php